# Как выдрать html с выполненным javascript в QWebEngineView?

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, парсер, qt5

Возможно ли это? Вот этот код выдирает Html но этот html вроде как без выполнного javascript, он без нужной мне инфы. В конце концов в WebEngineView вставляется то уже исполненный код, но как его получить?

```
#include <webpageparser.h>
#include <QTextEdit>
WebPageParser::WebPageParser(const QUrl &url)
{

    page.load(url); // url - адрес страницы, после вызова этого метода начинается загрузка страницы
    connect(&page, SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), this, SLOT(readHTML())); // сигнал loadFinished вызывается по окончании загрузки интернет страницы
    connect(&page, SIGNAL(loadProgress(int)), this, SLOT(loadProgress(int))); // сигнал loadProgress вызывается при каждом изменении состоянии загрузки
}

void WebPageParser::loadProgress(int progress)
{
    qDebug() << "progress = " << progress; // выводим текущее состояние загрузки в qDebug()
}


void WebPageParser::readHTML()
{
    QTextEdit *textEdit = new QTextEdit;
    page.toHtml([textEdit](const QString &result){
    qDebug() <<result;
    textEdit->setPlainText(result);
    }); // выводим html код страницы
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно запросить содержимое документа с помощью JavaScript в обработчике loadFinished:

```
webEngineView->setHtml(QStringLiteral(
                           "<html><body><p>Static content...</p>"
                           "<script>document.write('<p>Some dynamic content...</p>');"
                           "</script>"
                           "</body></html>"),
                       QUrl(QStringLiteral("http://localhost")));

connect(webEngineView->page(), &QWebEnginePage::loadFinished,
        this, [this, webEngineView]() noexcept
{
    webEngineView->page()->runJavaScript(
                QStringLiteral("document.documentElement.outerHTML;"),
                [](const QVariant& result) noexcept
    {
        qDebug("Current Content:\n%s", qPrintable(result.toString()));
    });
});
```

Comment: Спс. В принципе я узнал если подождать немного например в отдельном потоке, то код в toHtml тоже будет выполненным с javascript